# Which relatives are you obligated to stand up for when they recieve an Aliyah?

Tags: halacha, minhag

Does the requirement apply to uncles and older cousins? What about brother in law or my wife's uncle?

Comment: Hi David. Why do you think one must stand for a relative's Aliyah? Do  you have any sources that detail or mention this requirement? Please [edit] your post to clarify. While you may have heard of it, try not to assume everyone has.

Comment: For that matter, why is it necessary to stand for ANY aliyah?

Comment: I saw sifardim have a costom to sand for a father's Aliya, but by a Rav's Aliya even ashkenazi stand, I guess the reason is out of respect